# Is there a way to edit contacts birthdays on the phone?

Tags: contacts

As far as I can tell the default contacts app on the phone does not have a field to enter or edit birthdays.

Is there a way to do this?

What about other contact apps?

Comment: Running HTC Magic with 2.3 Gingerbread with the default contacts app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 4.4.2 one can edit the Contact, and if the birthday is not showing at all, scroll to the bottom and tap on the "Add another field" button, add a tick mark to "Events", then tap "OK".  The default event field shown will be "Birthday".  If you tap on the event type tag, it can be set to "Birthday", "Anniversary", "Other", or "Custom", where "Custom" can be edited to display an arbitrary string.  As of this writing, Google Contacts in one's Web browser only recognizes dates in the forms "MM/DD/YY", *e.g.*, "12/24/72", or "MMMM DD, YYYY", *e.g.*, "December 24, 1972".  It flags other formats as invalid, such as ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD). <sigh>  This can cause problems if contacts are imported from other sources that recognize ISO 8601.  Fortunately, if you enter the date on the Android side, it is constrained to the proper format by the "Set date" selector window and it also gives one the option to enter just the month and day if the year is unknown or irrelevant.

Multiple events can be created for a Contact entry.  In a test, I tapped the "+" repeatedly and in addition to "Birthday", created "Anniversary" and over 250 "Other" fields, but the Contact app never issued a warning that a limit been exceeded.

Answer (score 5):

On my phone, I can't enter contact's birthdays, but if I've previously entered their birthday on GMail then it does appear in their Contacts entry on the phone, and I can edit it there. Not that useful, as the birthday field is something you're likely to add to someone, and then its not very likely to ever change after that!

One workaround that I use if I'm entering this on the phone is to add their birthday into the Notes field, and then later on when I'm at a PC I can go into GMail and put the birthday in properly.

This is using the Contacts app on a Galaxy S using their stock Froyo  (2.2.1).

Comment: This issue is now resolved in Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS).

Answer (score 2):

I can edit the birthdays in the "People" app on my HTC Desire just fine (running Android 2.2). So maybe it's a phone-dependent thing?

Comment: The People app is part of HTC Sense, which is only on HTC branded phones running HTC Sense. This is separate from the standard Android Contacts app.

Comment: Perhaps the rumoured "People" app in Ice Cream Sandwich will let you do this.

Answer (score 2):

On my Google Nexus S, the only way I have found is to use browser access to my GMail contacts, or to log the birthday as a note then transfer later.

My HTC Incredible S can capture birthdays natively in the HTC People application, but overall I prefer the "native" Google look and feel to HTC's.

As far as I could tell looking at a Galaxy Nexus in a shop on release day, this is still true for Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS), at least in the native Google application.

Not good - hope it is fixed soon.

Comment: This is now fixed. We can probably delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

A more complicated solution but maybe the cleanest one, you can export your contacts and manually edit the .vcf (with Notepad++ for example), replace all the "END:VCARD" by "END:VCARD\n" to have a new line between each contact, and then manually add birthday for each contact.

A vcard looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Name;;;;
FN:Name
END:VCARD
```

So you'll want to add a BDAY field, for example if Name's birthday is October 22:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Name;;;;
FN:Name
BDAY:--10-22
END:VCARD
```

If you want to add a custom event it's a bit more complicated

```
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event;DATE;0;LABEL;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

For example

```
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event;2019-10-19;0;Rencontre;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Please see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties) for a list of properties and values format.

You can then import the vcf in the contacts app.

Please note that, like user31389's answer, the birthday will not appear on the contacts app, because it just doesn't support it, but other apps will be able to detect it, like the most important one: Birthday Calendar Adapter

Answer (score 1):

No, at this point in time, the only way is to go to the Contacts section in GMail and edit a contact's birthday AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was installing [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount) App, then create a new local account for my contacts. I could then add birthdays to contacts within this account (just like for contacts in the google account), which didn't work for the normal "Phone" account.
I moved my contacts from "Phone" to local account using [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at).

Answer (score 1):

Android Contacts is missing a date entry field (or missing any add entry field) on my Android 6.0 Motorola 3g phone. I found that the contacts entry in my standard Android phone app does have a date field. It is different. Curious.
The standard Android phone app date field can be used for birthdays. So, go into your phone app, the one with the blue phone icon, select the contacts tab on top. Then select a contact. Then select the edit icon (a pencil. Find it at the top of the page.). Find the More Fields menu item at the bottom. Select it. Flip down to find the date icon and entry line. It looks like a tiny calendar. The entry line has a down arrow on its right where you can enter the birthday date. Under the Date line is a category for the date. Select birthday.
Once this is accomplished, the next birthday entry will be much faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on LineageOS, Android 9. Fortunately I've found the Simple Contacts app.

- Play Store:
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.contacts.pro
- F-Droid:
  https://f-droid.org/packages/com.simplemobiletools.contacts.pro
- GitHub: https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Contacts

It allows you to add and edit birthdays, in addition to your usual contacts management. It's open-source. The Google Play version is paid, the F-Droid version is free (though I still encourage you to donate to its author). It's a part of a suite of apps, called Simple Mobile Tools.