# Adding events field to contact

Tags: contacts

I have a smartphone that running on android 4.1.1. When I create new contact or edit existing one, I want to add field with birthday of the person. The problem is I can't choose to add new field with type 'Events', there is no such option in menu after I click button "Add another field" when I edit/create contact. So the question is: how can I enable Events to be added when I work with my Contacts (like on the image below).

[image: adding new field to my contact info]

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8417/is-there-a-way-to-edit-contacts-birthdays-on-the-phone) is related?

Comment: @AndrewT. , I have another smartphone (one I've taken screenshot from). It's Huawei Honor u8860. Its default Contacts app has Events. Of course, it might be only modification by Huawei developers and other Android devices doesn't necessarily have it.